# How to improve this question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Is there a way [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/is-communism-bad) can be improved ?

Answer (score 2):

"Bad" is a [value judgement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_judgment) and thus subjective. The question could be rephrased to ask for an **objective** assessment of communism. For example, you could ask if communism reduces poverty rates, increases GDP, causes social problems, or something similar. Make the question ask something specific and objective.

As far as improving the question in general, the question mentions some background reading on communism. If it's relevant, the question could mention some historical examples of countries which have tried communism, what resulted, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** "Communism" is not really the right word to use in this context. There are and have been different incarnations of the communist ideals, but they differ by a very large amount.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communism#Marxist_schools_of_communism
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communism#Non-Marxist_schools

So the question is much too wide to be acceptable.

**2.** "Bad" does not provide an adequate criterion for making a judgment call.

**3.** Pointing to an inflammatory source does not help the question

---

The question could be acceptable, if marginally interesting and possibly borderline off-topic, if rephrased as such:

I have read about communism in history and it didn't sound this bad, but on the net I have found extreme opinions like:

> Remember also that "equality" to a communist means the equality of slavery. Under the commies, Everyone will be an equal slave! Unfortunately, there are many people around today that would prefer the equality of slavery to the inequities of freedom
>   -- [source](http://www.communismisbad.bravehost.com/)

Does any of the [different communism incarnations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communism#Marxist_schools_of_communism) predicate that people should be all equal, but as slaves?

Comment: i edited my question as you suggested.